# Change status bar back to default after changing it to `Light`, per view Controller scenario

Tags: ios7, uiapplication, uistatusbar

I want to be able to change the status bar color on a per view controller basis. My ViewController flow is A->B->C. The launch status bar color is black (in A), and I change it to white in view Controller B. I use the following in Bs `viewDidLoad`:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
 [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

Which works perfectly. However when I go back to ViewController A, it is white also. I tried using the following code to change it back but it doesnt work:

```
 [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleDefault];
 [self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];
```

I also tried:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarStyle = UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent;
```

But its deprecated and doesnt work.

I have seen the other questions on SO about this, but they tell you how to change it but not change back to default.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Setting the navigation bar back to default in `viewWillAppear` did the trick.